# Are lrprev files in Lightroom just previews that I do not need to back up?

Tags: adobe-lightroom

In Adobe Lightroom, it is my understanding that the .lrprev files it creates, are only previews of pictures, but that these can be regenerated from the real pictures in case of disaster.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Correct.

Lightroom stores its previews under (for example) `Lightroom 3 Catalog Previews.lrdata`, which itselfs contains the single previews in  a folder hierarchy. You don't even need the whole `.lrdata` folder.

In fact, when you back up your catalog, Lightroom will only back up the `.lrcat` file. Do note though that those previews can come in handy in case you lose your originals, since you can export the previews from the `.lrprev` files.

See also: [Adobe forums](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3848096#3848096) — same thing suggested there.

Comment: Thanks. Seeing as it is only 2GB out of 43GB total for my Lightroom folder, I will continue to back it up then.